# Will my system crash randomly if I use RAM DIMMs of different capacities?

Tags: memory, computer-building

I currently have Gigabyte [GA-B250M-DS3H](https://www.amazon.in/dp/B01N2WG23X) mother-board and 1x [8GB DDR4 RAM](https://www.amazon.in/dp/B00SV7IILC) with 2133MHz speed and CAS latency of 16.

Now if I install 1x [16GB DDR4 RAM](https://www.amazon.in/dp/B01K3LTX8U) with 2400MHz speed and CAS latency of 16.

Is my system going to be unstable?

I know that if there are RAM with different speeds the faster one automatically down clocked to match the slowest one.

I do not require fast memory speed, even dual channel is not my concern, I just need more capacity.

Furthermore I Googled and looked for similar topics in sites like Tom’s Hardware but the answers are mixed, some says yes, some says technically it should and some says no, so I am confused.

Lastly I know most people suggest going for the identical DIMMs but right now that 16GB DIMM is cheaper on Amazon than my current DIMM.

Comment: Generally no, you can use RAM's of different capacities with no issues.

Comment: No. Especially not with modern systems. Your system will not crash.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, that does actually clear the confusion thanks again CaldeiraG and JakeGould

Answer (score 0):

The RAM seems to be compatible, but I cannot of course guarantee it.

If you check the
[Crucial website](https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/GIGABYTE/ga-b250m-ds3h),
it guarantees the compatibility of RAM sticks that seem very similar to yours.

The specs of your
[VENGEANCE® LPX 16GB (1 x 16GB) DDR4 DRAM 2400MHz C16 Memory Kit](https://www.corsair.com/uk/en/Categories/Products/Memory/VENGEANCE-LPX/p/CMK16GX4M1A2400C16#tab-tech-specs):

[image]

The Crucial
[Crucial 16GB Kit (2 x 8GB) DDR4-2400 UDIMM](https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/ga-b250m-ds3h/CT9795482):

[image]

Final note about prices: Your price in Indian Rupees translates to $71.35.
The Crucial stick is $63.99 and is guaranteed (but I don't know about shipping costs).

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I bought that 16 GB DIMM which I mentioned in the question,
Installed it in the different slot, different colored slot, because I thought dual channel would mess something up.

Both DIMMS 8GB and 16 GB running on 2133 MHz speed, as I mentioned faster one automatically gets down clocked.

It has been nearly 2 weeks and everything is working fine no crashes.

Lastly Thank you everyone for the help really appreciate it.